# Hypothesis testing problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

(This is a homework question)

Listed below are ages of actresses and actors at the time that they won an award for the categories of Best Actress and Best Actor. Use the sample data to test for a difference between the ages of actresses and actors when they win the award. Use a 0.10 significance level. Assume that the paired sample data is a simple random sample and that the differences have a distribution that is approximately normal.

```
Actress's age

16
31
20
60
27

​Actor's age

41
43
61
50
41
```

What is the conclusion based on the hypothesis​ test?